I want to connect Prisma with Mongodb locally
I am gonna build one project which has to connect prisma with Mongodb locally.
I have set the database url as follows.
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://name:password@localhost:27017/Cluster1"
When I push prisma db, there are some errors as follows.
Error: Iterating on one schema using re-introspection with db pull is currently not supported with MongoDB provider.
How can I fix this problem?
I tried to find proper way to push prisma db to the Mongodb locally.
But there is an error.

From a bit of searching I'm thinking you are trying to connect to a database with data, but you don't have a schema?
